# ViewPager in listview

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, parse-platform

I have created a list of items that is populated using Parse data. Instead of returning a list of users in a single page, i would prefer if only one user details was returned per page  and where to see the other users in the list you could swipe left and right between as oppose to viewing it one long list.

To achieve this I have looked into [the Google view pager tutorials](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html) -

However, I am having issues working that out. Below is what I have tried, and where I am experiencing issues. The `activity` that generates users on a `list`

```
public class MatchingActivity extends Activity {
 private String currentUserId;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> namesArrayAdapter;
    private ArrayList<String> names;
    private ListView usersListView;
    private Button logoutButton;
    String userGender = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getString("Gender");
    String activityName = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getString("ActivityName");
    Number maxDistance = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getNumber("Maximum_Distance");


    String userLookingGender = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getString("Looking_Gender");
    Number minimumAge = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getNumber("Minimum_Age");
    Number maximumAge = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getNumber("Maximum_Age");


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.matching);

        logoutButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.logoutButton);
        logoutButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ParseUser.logOut();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        setConversationsList();
    }
    private void setConversationsList() {
        currentUserId = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId();
        names = new ArrayList<String>();
      // String userActivitySelectionName = null;

           ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();

         //  query.whereEqualTo("ActivityName",userActivitySelectionName);

           query.whereNotEqualTo("objectId", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId());
           // users with Gender = currentUser.Looking_Gender
           query.whereEqualTo("Gender", userLookingGender);
           // users with Looking_Gender = currentUser.Gender
           query.whereEqualTo("Looking_Gender", userGender);
           query.whereEqualTo("ActivityName", activityName);
           query.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("Minimum_Age", minimumAge);
           query.whereLessThanOrEqualTo("Maximum_Age", maximumAge);
  //  query.whereWithinKilometers("Maximum_Distance", point, maxDistance)





        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {

            public void done(List<ParseUser> userList, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    for (int i=0; i<userList.size(); i++) {
                        names.add(userList.get(i).get("Name").toString());
                        names.add(userList.get(i).get("Headline").toString());
                        names.add(userList.get(i).get("Age").toString());
                 //       names.add(userList.get(i).getParseObject("ProfilePicture").;


                    }




                    usersListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.usersListView);
                    namesArrayAdapter =
                        new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                            R.layout.user_list_item, names);
                    usersListView.setAdapter(namesArrayAdapter);

                    usersListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int i, long l) {
                            openConversation(names, i);
                        }
                    });

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Error loading user list",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void openConversation(ArrayList<String> names, int pos) {
        ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
        query.whereEqualTo("Name", names.get(pos));
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
           public void done(List<ParseUser> user, ParseException e) {
               if (e == null) {
                   Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MessagingActivity.class);
                   intent.putExtra("RECIPIENT_ID", user.get(0).getObjectId());
                   startActivity(intent);
               } else {
                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                       "Error finding that user",
                           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }
           }
        });
    }
}
```

Below is the `ViewPager FragmentActivity` that displays 5 page, I am having major difficulty setting up where each page would display a different user information.

```
public class ScreenSlideActivity extends FragmentActivity {
/**
 * The number of pages (wizard steps) to show in this demo.
 */
private static final int NUM_PAGES = 5;

/**
 * The pager widget, which handles animation and allows swiping horizontally to access previous
 * and next wizard steps.
 */
private ViewPager mPager;

/**
 * The pager adapter, which provides the pages to the view pager widget.
 */
private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_screen_slide);

    // Instantiate a ViewPager and a PagerAdapter.
    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
    mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
    mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // When changing pages, reset the action bar actions since they are dependent
            // on which page is currently active. An alternative approach is to have each
            // fragment expose actions itself (rather than the activity exposing actions),
            // but for simplicity, the activity provides the actions in this sample.
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_screen_slide, menu);

    menu.findItem(R.id.action_previous).setEnabled(mPager.getCurrentItem() > 0);

    // Add either a "next" or "finish" button to the action bar, depending on which page
    // is currently selected.
    MenuItem item = menu.add(Menu.NONE, R.id.action_next, Menu.NONE,
            (mPager.getCurrentItem() == mPagerAdapter.getCount() - 1)
                    ? R.string.action_finish
                    : R.string.action_next);
    item.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            // Navigate "up" the demo structure to the launchpad activity.
            // See http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html for more.
            NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this, new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
            return true;

        case R.id.action_previous:
            // Go to the previous step in the wizard. If there is no previous step,
            // setCurrentItem will do nothing.
            mPager.setCurrentItem(mPager.getCurrentItem() - 1);
            return true;

        case R.id.action_next:
            // Advance to the next step in the wizard. If there is no next step, setCurrentItem
            // will do nothing.
            mPager.setCurrentItem(mPager.getCurrentItem() + 1);
            return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A simple pager adapter that represents 5 {@link ScreenSlidePageFragment} objects, in
 * sequence.
 */
private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return ScreenSlidePageFragment.create(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_PAGES;
    }
}
}
```

I am really confused on this, and if you could assist me that would be helpful.

I hope I was clear, and if you need further clarification, let me know.

Comment: Can you exactly explain what your problem is? Beeing confused isn´t something others can answer. What´s not working? What are your issues?

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response, and agree that people can't answer confusion. What I have working is an activity that populates a list using ParseQuery, where it draws items such as "Name", "Headline" and age, if various criteria are met. My issue is that I do not want a long list to be populated on a single activity page, instead I want only 1 user information (name, headline, age) to be displayed per activity page, and where users could navigate left and right through the list using swipe view. I have tried working with viewpager (code in my initial post), but i am confused

Comment: I hope my clarification helped. I have trying to figure out this issue for weeks, and hence any assistance would be helpful